# is square payment support the ionic framework(hybrid mobile application)

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, square-connect

I am new to the **square** payment I try to create the mobile application in the **ionic framework** which is the **hybrid application**.
I try to integrate the **sypaymentform** in javascript but I have doubt like its support the ionic framework and once completed the one transaction,it's not generates the form for next transaction.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: ya completed this square payment method what I did is every time I clear the form so it creates a new form every time.